# htaccess redirect www to non www blocking bing bot

Tags: .htaccess

This htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(ico|css|png|jpg|gif|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I've had it for over a month, and now I see that it was blocking bing bot from crawling and indexing my site (when I fetch with bingbot it says unexpected error). When I remove the first three lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It fetches good, but now the site won't redirect from www to non-www

The first rewrite is from www to non-www, second is from http:// to https://, and the rest of the code is for my php script seo urls.